# Почему на созданной ветке не удается запушить

Tags: git

я нахожусь на созданной ветке допустим `branch-02`. Я решил по алгоритму внести изменения  и закоммитить, затем в той же ветке хочу отправить на удаленный репо свой проект при команде:

```
git push origin master
```

выводит:

```
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Everything up-to-date
```

все таки мне по правилам гит стоит перейти на ветку `master` , а потом уже смерджить  из `branch-02`, ну а дальше пушить на удаленку

Comment: Зачем вы пушите вашу ветку не являющуюся мастером в мастер?

Comment: создал я ветку branch-02,  дальше выводит тот же результат, когда делаю push

Comment: если быть точнее, на удаленном репо я создал ветку branch-02. У меня указывает, что две ветки, а как тогда я могу слить туда свои изменения, pull request для чего ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть два пути:

1. Путь первый
   Запушить ветку branch-02 на удалённый репозиторий и уже на удалённом репозитории сделать
   `git merge branch-02`
2. Путь второй
   Локально сделать мердж ветки branch-02 в мастер а потом мастер запушить в удалённый репозиторий. Вот только мерджить в мастер не рекомендую)

Comment: почему во втором варианте, вы не рекомендуете сливать в мастер, по какой причине

Comment: а почему не рекомендуете?

Comment: а в первом варианте не удается запушить, выше я указывал ошибку

Comment: Эта не ошибка а простое сообщение что у вас нет изменений в мастере и это логично вы же находитесь в ветке `branch-02`. Вы наверное не внимательно команду посмотрели нам не `push` а `merge`

Comment: Порядок действий в вашем случае:
`git add .` (либо файлы которые вы хотите изменить)
`git commit -m"сообщение"`
`git push origin branch-02`
На удалённом репозитории(если есть)
`git checkout master`
`git pull origin master`(вдруг есть изменения не от Вас)
`git merge branch-02`
Готово

Answer (score 1):

вообще команда `push` отправляет изменения из *источника* в *назначение*.

командой `push origin master` вы указываете лишь источник — локальную ветку `master`. назначение в таком случае берётся из конфигурации вашего хранилища (по умолчанию удалённая ветка `master`).

из локальной ветки `master` нечего отправлять в удалённую `master`, о чём вам программа *git* и сообщает:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

---

а что же вам делать — зависит от того, чего именно вы хотите добиться.

если вы хотите добиться, чтобы изменения локальной ветки `branch-02` добавились к удалённой ветке `master`, укажите **оба** «конца» — и источник и назначение:

```
$ git push origin branch-02:master
```

Comment: ааа... все.. все..  теперь дошло)))) искренне выражаю благодарность!!  не судите строго, я только учусь, мне все безумно интересно

Comment: @John, примите ответ, если он вам помог